How to find count of groups a particular IDs belong to in Snowflake?
I have a following data that a 5 groups which has certain IDs. One ID can be a part of multiple groups. I would like to find in how many group each ID is in.
Initial Data
Result:
Result
I did this excel but I want do it in snowflake
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried to use
Select ID, COUNT(Group)
FROM _Database
and expecting
Result
but it says not a valid group by expression.

You should add the group by clause in your query , if it still gives some error, please send us the table sample, with some sample data and expecte output.
Select ID, COUNT(Group) FROM _Database GROUP BY ID;


Thank you Himanshu, that worked like a Charm!!!!
